# How to respond when someone says “give me an example” or “like what” but nothing comes to mind at that moment

Tags: meaning

Has it ever happened to you that you are explaining something you know and then someone asks you for examples but nothing comes to mind and you have to reply in a way that doesn’t sound like you actually don’t know but that you do know but can't recall at that moment.

Comment: Ashley, you look like an English speaker via your name? Aren't you an English speaker?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm drawing a blank.

This is a set phrase meaning you can't recall any examples. Your mind is "blank."

> It's on the tip of my tongue.

Another idiom meaning you can't think of the right word(s), but you feel like the memory could come to you at any moment. You might even be able to recall characteristics of the word or phrase -- for example, you know it starts with an *S*.

> It escapes me.

This means you know the right response, but it has "escaped" temporarily from your mind.